# python Spark avro

Tags: python, apache-spark, avro

When attempting to write avro, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 35.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.0 in stage 35.0 (TID 110, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroWrapper
```

I had read in an avro file with 3 records using:

```
avro_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
    "threerecords.avro",
    "org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat",
    "org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey",
    "org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
    keyConverter="org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.AvroWrapperToJavaConverter",
    conf=None)

output = avro_rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()
```

Then I tried to write out a single record (output kept in avro) with:

```
conf = {"avro.schema.input.key": reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, sc.textFile("myschema.avsc", 1).collect())}

sc.parallelize([output[0]]).map(lambda x: (x, None)).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
    "output.avro",
    "org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyOutputFormat",
    "org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey",
    "org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
    keyConverter="org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.AvroWrapperToJavaConverter",
    conf=conf)
```

How do I get around that error/write out an individual avro record succsssfully? I know my schema is correct because it is from the avro itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this isn't supported at the moment. You are now trying to use the java map as an Avro Record and covert it to a Java map again. That's why you get the error the error about the java hashmap.

There is a pull request from staslos to add the Avro output format, see [link](https://github.com/staslos/spark/commit/ef026be7981c6d892e2d2e35e8b100c9def2dd6a) for the pull request and the example.

There is a converter required which is missing in AvroConverters.scala to convert from the java map back to the avro format.

Comment: Is it possible for me to use the pull request in a precompiled binary of Spark 1.3.0? If so, how? It looks like the pull request has been open for quite a while..

Comment: It looks like the scala files get compiled at runtime. So it should be possible to apply the patch file on your spark installation. Search for the scala file from the patch and apply it. Now you should be able (maybe after a spark restart) to use it from python as showed in the patch example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem last week. Based on rfkortekass answer, I used the pull request from  staslos and tried to setup a simple example of reading / writing in avro files.

I managed to get a simple demo working. You can find the files here 
https://github.com/totor31/spark-avro-python-converters

I know nothing to scala, java nor maven, so this is very experimental : my main target was to extract a very limited amount of files from spark examples directory, in order to get a compilation framework that permits generating a usable jar file.

If somebody more knowledgeable wants to interact with my repository, feel free to ask.

Many thanks to rfkortekass for pointing the pull request, it saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Comming back a few month later :

using spark DataFrames in new version is a good way to write avro files : see https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro